# How to navigate to a particular section in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have tried to navigate to a specific section inside a page

i have tried to add id in the component but it did't work like
<Login id ="login_section >

Comment: Please provide more details like What do you mean by navigating to section? How are you navigating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const goToSection=(id)=>{
    const targetSection = document.getElementById(id);
    if(targetSection != null) {
      window.scrollTo({
        top:targetSection.offsetTop,
        behavior:"smooth",
      });
    }
  }
```

Or You can use useRef hook.